# If you were just unplugged from The Matrix, and all muscles had atrophied bc they'd never been used, what PT exercises would you need to do?

Tags: physical-therapy

I know this is a weird question, but I'm just curious, so please humor me. I'm hoping someone (maybe a physical therapist?) in this forum might be able to give a legit answer? I'm curious to know what would be needed to physically build the human body from the ground up using basic exercises.

So imagine this premise... Neo has just been unplugged from The Matrix.  Therefore all his muscles are atrophied (because he has never able to stand, walk, run, etc). However, in this version, Morpheus doesn't have those fancy electronics to stimulate his muscles, so he strictly has to use basic bodyweight exercises. Like when one goes to Physical Therapy.

So what would he need to do in order to be able to stand, walk, run, etc like a normal person? And in what progression would he need to do them in? One needn't go into great detail. Just a listing your thoughts of the progressing exercises would be enough me :)

Thanks!

Comment: in the movie they _do_ apply some sort of electric stimulation through those acupuncture needles when he's unplugged... It seems it goes on for a while before he can walk